# Android SQLite - attempt to re-open an already-closed object. What might be closing my database?

Tags: android, sqlite, concurrency

I'm the author of an Android library project that is frequently included in other apps.  I use a small SQLite database for storage, which is accessed via android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.

When the app starts, the database helper creates the database (if needed), calls dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(), and uses the returned dbHelper reference for all database access.  Important to note:

- Only the helper has access to the SQLiteDatabase object that is created.
- I do not call SQLiteDatabase.close() on the database at any point.  I know that is a frequent cause of this issue but that's not the case here.
- The apps that use my library are frequently multi-threaded.  Inserts are done in batches, which are synchronized thusly:

  ```
  public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  ...
  ...
  ...

      public void insertBatch(LinkedList<DatabaseRecord> writeQueue) {

      Iterator<DatabaseRecord> it = writeQueue.iterator();

      synchronized (this) {
          try {
              this.open();
              db.beginTransaction();

              while (it.hasNext()) {
                  DatabaseRecord record = it.next();

                  Long lDate = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
                  initialValues.put(aa, record.aa);
                  initialValues.put(bb, record.bb);
                  initialValues.put(cc, record.cc);
                  initialValues.put(dd, lDate);

                  db.insert(DBTBL, null, initialValues);
              }
              db.setTransactionSuccessful();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Utility.logError(logtag, "Error inserting batch record into database.", e);
          } finally {
              db.endTransaction();  // sometimes throws "already-closed" exception!
              this.close();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

The problem, as you can see in the comment, is that the endTransaction() call sometimes throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.xxx.yyy/databases/db near/at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference:55
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.xxx.yyy/databases/db
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:535)
  at com.aaa.bbb.DatabaseHelper.insertBatch(DatabaseHelper.java:273)
  at com.aaa.bbb.WriteQueue.flushQueue(WriteQueue.java:88)
  at com.aaa.bbb.WriteQueue.run(WriteQueue.java:77)
```

This works 99.95% of the time.  But, oddly, it fails in a small percentage of cases.  In looking at the places where it fails, there is one consistency: there are other SQLite databases present.  In these cases, there are other third-party libraries that are calling SQLiteDatabase.close() directly.

Is it possible that this is closing **all** of the database instances on the device?  Is there even a way to do that?

Comment: `this.close();` is closing it

Comment: this.close() is done last, though.  It is failing BEFORE I call close.  It's opened before the batch insert begins and closed in the finally block.  Something else is closing my database before the batch insert is complete.  Access into this open/insert/close logic is synchronized, so even if insertBatch() is called from two threads simultaneously, only one of them can open/insert/close at a time.

Comment: Hey @AWT, did you manage to solve it? I am having the same problem and only with a very small percentage of users...

Comment: Hi @tomacco, unfortunately no, I never found the root cause for this. My solution was to catch the exception and re-open the database if needed, and then try the transaction again.